# Read In JSON File Into TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I've created a JSON file and want to read it into TypeScript so I can return it on a function call.

However I keep getting the error:

```
[ts] Cannot find module './example.json'.
```

Here is my example.json which is running from same location of current file

```
{"cars": ["red", "green"] }
```

And here is my TypeScript

```
declare module "*.json" {
const value: any;
export default value;
}import * as data from './example.json';

function getJson {
const word = (<any>data).cars;
console.log(word);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add into your typings.d.ts the code:

```
declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

and in your actual .ts file you can simply:

```
import * as dataJSON from './example.json';
```

and than you can use it as an object. for example:

```
console.log((<any>dataJSON.cars[0] ));
// console.log --> red
```

Comment: what if your project doesn't have a typings.d.ts?

Comment: You create it! Under `src`